# Can't set proper height on an image div with overlay on small screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a block on my website that I want to have a background image with an overlay on top to make it less visible, and then some content on top of that. I want the height of the div/image/content to be at least 100vh on large screens, but on smaller screens it needs to be higher since the content covers more than 100vh.

I tried the following but the text overflows the div and the image is only at 100vh still.

```css
.homepage-top-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.homepage-top-image-wrapper .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.homepage-top-image-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.home-content-block {
  max-width: 1100px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage-top-image-wrapper">
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/17/72/47/360_F_317724775_qHtWjnT8YbRdFNIuq5PWsSYypRhOmalS.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="home-content-block">        
      <div class="home-content-subtitle" style="font-size:5rem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

    </div>          
  </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using your content inside `overlay` that is absolutely positioned so the height of your content won't be the height of your main container `homepage-top-image-wrapper`.

you can change your html structure like this:

```
<div class="homepage-top-image-wrapper">
<img class="image" src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/17/72/47/360_F_317724775_qHtWjnT8YbRdFNIuq5PWsSYypRhOmalS.jpg" alt="">
<div class="overlay"> 
</div>    
<div class="home-content-block">        
  <div class="home-content-subtitle" style="font-size:5rem">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

now your container will resize by the content.

you have to change your css accordingly to achieve same thing as before:

```
.homepage-top-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


.homepage-top-image-wrapper .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.homepage-top-image-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #00000080;
}

.home-content-block {
  max-width: 1100px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Just one detail: The image gets pushes together if I make the screen narrower (e.g. mobile). I tried to add background-position: center and     background-size: cover; but it did nothing. How can I make the image always cover the space but not lose its aspect ratio?

Comment: you're welcome. To achieve that you can remove `img` tag in html and add background image to `homepage-top-image-wrapper` and then set `background-size`. 

Also there are `object-fit` and `object-position` properties in css for images and videos that works almost like `background-position` and `background-size` for background.